# Require PHP/Javascript code to display Elementor popup "ONCE PER SESSION" for users

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, popup, elementor

I require an Elementor popup to display only once per session. The popup should display on all pages expect home page and another page.

For this I tried the following code in Code Snippets plugin (HTML) for that specific page by adding shortcode to the page.

```
<script>
;((w,d) => {
    w.addEventListener('elementor/frontend/init', ()=>{
        const $ = jQuery;
        let popupsClosed = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('popupName_closed')) || [];
        $( d ).on( 'elementor/popup/hide', (e,id) => {
            if(false === popupsClosed.includes(id)){
                popupsClosed.push(id);
                sessionStorage.setItem('popupName_closed', JSON.stringify(popupsClosed));
            }
        })
        elementorFrontend.on( 'components:init' , ()=>{
            const popupId = 1234;
            if(false === popupsClosed.includes(popupId)){
                elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( { id:popupId });
            }
         
         });
    })
})(window,document)
</script>
```

The code works fine when popup is set to immediately show on website. But this code does not work when popup is set to display 3 sec after page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

Test page: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9qvwhg1j/

```js
((w, d) => {
  w.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let popupsSeen = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('popups_Seen') || 'false');
    if (popupsSeen) return;
    setTimeout(() => {
      const popupId = 1234;
      elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup({
        id: popupId
      });
      sessionStorage.setItem('popups_Seen', JSON.stringify(true));
    }, 3000);
  });
})(window, document);
```

Comment: Still not working! The popup is getting displayed 3 sec after page load, even after a key "popups_Seen" with value "true" is created in sessionStorage.

Comment: Then there is likely somewhere else you show them. The code above will not show anything if the sessionStorage is parsed to true. My code works. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9qvwhg1j/)

Comment: I show the popup through Elementor on a specific page. On setting not to display the popup on that page, the code executes, just "showPopup" does not show any popup. The key value pair is still being added.

Comment: You need to remove the other code of course. My code replaces all the code to popup and to delay 3 seconds